# How do I find the exact value of cot theta from the value of sin theta

Tags: trigonometry

This is the only value given, and it is stated that theta is an acute angle. What is the formula for finding the exact value of cot theta from sin theta please?

Answer (score 1):

Fof an acute angle $y=\sin \theta$, $x=\sqrt{1-y^2}$, $\cot \theta ={x \over y}$.

Answer (score 0):

If we know $\sin\theta=x$ and $\theta$ is acute (i.e., $0<\theta<\pi/2$),
then $\theta=\arcsin x$. Therefore, 
$$
\cot\theta=\frac{1}{\tan\theta}=\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}=\frac{\cos(\arcsin x)}{\sin(\arcsin x)}=\frac{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{x}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The sine of an angle $\theta$ refers to the ratio between the opposite and hypotenuse sides to the angle $\theta$ of a right triangle. Given that
$$\sin \theta=a$$
For some number $a$, that means that the triangle has opposite side length $a$ and hypotenuse length $1$. The cotangent refers to the ratio between the adjacent and opposite sides, so we must find the lengths of these two sides. We know the length of the side opposite $\theta$ is $a$, and by the pythagorean theorem, the length of the adjacent side is $\sqrt{1-a^2}$. Now we know that our ratio is
$$\cot \theta=\frac{\sqrt{1-a^2}}{a}$$